# Safari on iO7 CSS issue with background-size

Tags: html, safari, ios7, css

I have a problem with Safari on iOS7. The problem is about having sprite images for retina so on Safari on iOS7 and background-size (I think so). It works well on Chrome on iOS7, but on Safari doesn't. Code that is in use is:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {

    footer ul.social li a { background-size: 48px 144px; }
    footer ul.social li a.fb { background: url(../images/socialx2.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
    footer ul.social li a.in { background: url(../images/socialx2.png) 0 -48px no-repeat; }
    footer ul.social li a.tw { background: url(../images/socialx2.png) 0 -96px no-repeat; }

}
```

Here's an image of how it looks like on Safari under IOS7

[image: screen capture]

Comment: I've just had a client ask about it. I don't have ios7 to play with but it seems like background-size isn't working to me.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. It doesn't work either for sprite and non-sprite graphic. Such a shame

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On safari / iOS7, background-size is reseted when using the background property.
You need to specify background-property after your background :

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    footer ul.social li a.fb { background: url(../images/socialx2.png) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: 48px 144px; }
    footer ul.social li a.in { background: url(../images/socialx2.png) 0 -48px no-repeat; background-size: 48px 144px; }
    footer ul.social li a.tw { background: url(../images/socialx2.png) 0 -96px no-repeat; background-size: 48px 144px; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Was wondering why my css wasn't working anymore.

Comment: And not just that. It looks like it works only if the background and background-size are specified in the same ruleset. 
ie.. 
#css-selector{
   background: url('') no-repeat;
}

#css-selector{
  background-size: '';
}

doesn't work. Bad Job Apple !!

Comment: This media query will also affect Retina Mac Screens (tested between retina and non-retina).  Just FYI.

Comment: for cover `background: ...; background-size: cover;`